# ReactJS + MUIv5 with styled-engine-sc - Styling Drawer with styled components in flexbox

Tags: css, reactjs, material-ui, styled-components

Hello Stackoverflow community,

I trying to use a custom styled drawer within a flexbox container with the new way - the usage of the styled-engine-sc. I used that one as template and tried to convert it to the styled-components: Source:
https://codesandbox.io/s/vmx7z4kx33

I have the problem that the flexbox is not working in my converted project, look here:
https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-margulis-r9w0dv

The content is going behind the drawer.
Can somebody help me to solve that problem?

Comment: can nobody help me with that problem?

Comment: Please see [ask] and take the [tour]. Your question doesn't meet site standards.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. The problem was the explicit root class for drawer - in styled-components it has to be only on the toplevel without a subclass node.